# How to run a trigger mysql after startup database mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is possible to run a trigger to start the mysql database on the same oracle database?
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/DatabaseleveltriggerAFTERSTARTUPONDATABASE.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no.
In MySQL, triggers are strictly associated to tables, and can only be fired in response to a table event.
For a complete list of triggering events, take a look at the [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) page.